# The derivative of the wave function at the boundary of the wall with potential $U_0$ ($m_1 \neq m_2$)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

In the potential barrier, if a particle in an environment with a potential of $U_1$ hits a potential barrier with $U_2$ and suppose its energy is less than $U_2$.

Now my question is that if the mass of the particle changes in the second environment, then the wave function and its derivative must be the same at the boundary because of continuity.

The following formula is for Schrödinger:

$$ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m(x)}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} + V(x)\psi = E\psi $$

Continuity of the wave function:

$$ \psi_1(0) = \psi_2(0) $$

Continuity of the derivative of the wave function:

$$ \frac{1}{m_1} \frac{d\psi_1}{dx}(0) = \frac{1}{m_2} \frac{d\psi_2}{dx}(0) $$

The equation in different environmental conditions:

In region $1$ ($x \lt 0$):

$$ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{m_1}\frac{d^2\psi_1}{dx^2}\right) + V_1\psi_1 = E\psi_1 $$

In region $2$ ($x \gt 0$):

$$ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{m_2}\frac{d^2\psi_2}{dx^2}\right) + V_2\psi_1 = E\psi_2 $$

Now my question is, don't we have potential, so how do I get a derivative without considering the potential?

It is acceptable that the wave function at the boundary should be one and its derivative is also correct, but I don't understand that when we involve the mass, it should be the potential term to get the answer.

I hope my explanation was complete.

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of posting an image.